# Java EE JBoss JMS connection factory is null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jms

I tried now for a long time to get from JBoss a valid QueueConnectionFactory object. But it is always null. So I tried several JNDI entries, which are also listed in the config.

```
// @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory")
 @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
 private QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

I've got no idea anymore what is wrong and will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found the solution:

The code above does only with within a (stateless?) session-bean (Jboss). But I tried to run it inside a class which is called by url (@path).

I don't understand why. But maybe someone can explain it to me?